# Absolute path doesn't work, "Can't resolve"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app, absolute-path

So i tried to set up an absolute path for my project so I found out I need to make a .env file with following command:

```
NODE_PATH=src
```

Then I modified my import paths from './FileName' to 'FileName' ex.

```
import Root from 'views/Root/Root';
```

and run **npm start** command, then I got an error in terminal:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/index.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'views/Root/Root' in 'C:\Users\hisza\Desktop\unnamed\src'
```

When I change to relative path, everything works with no errors, any ideas why I get that error?
I use create-react-app with eslint, nothing more

Comment: What's the folder structure inside `C:\Users\hisza\Desktop\unnamed\src`?

Comment: @nathan [link](https://imgur.com/a/apN846I) Here's an imgur link for my folder structure

Answer (score 1):

Okay I made it using jsconfig.json file instead of .env and everything works

jsconfig.js file is in my main folder and contains:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "src"
    },
    "include": ["src"]
}
```